# Sqlite how to preserve order of INSERT

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a tab delimited file that is chronologically ordered by ascending timestamp. Each row has 7 columns. Each column is a parameter.

I have a sqlite database that I INSERT the rows from the tab file as parameters in a bulk INSERT command. For example:

```
 public void Create(IEnumerable<Game> items)
{
    var sbFields = new StringBuilder();
    sbFields.Append("ID,");
    sbFields.Append("LEAGUE,");
    sbFields.Append("VISITORTEAM,");
    sbFields.Append("HOMETEAM,");
    sbFields.Append("DATETIME,");
    sbFields.Append("VISITORSCORE,");
    sbFields.Append("HOMESCORE");

    int numAppended = 7;

    var sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numAppended; i++)
    {
        sbParams.Append("@param");
        sbParams.Append(i);

        if (i < numAppended)
        {
            sbParams.Append(", ");
        }
    }

    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(Db))
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO GAMES (" + sbFields + ") VALUES(" + sbParams + ")";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (var transaction = Db.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var game in items)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", game.Id));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param2", game.League));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param3", game.VisitorTeam));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param4", game.HomeTeam));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param5", game.Date.Ticks));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param6", game.VisitorScore));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param7", game.HomeScore));

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that when I retrieve the Game list from the database that it would be in the same order that I did the INSERT (in chronological order), but is not: in fact it is in what appears almost random order. Because of this, I have to sort the Game list after I read it from the database. And this operation is very slow. I do not want to sort. I want to read it in the same order that I INSERT.

Is this possible? Note: I do **not** want to add a new parameter (column) indicating the order. That seems like an artificial solution to me begging for future problems.

Here is how I read it from the database:

```
public IEnumerable<Game> Read()
{
    List<Game> enumerable = new List<Game>();

    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(Db))
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GAMES";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Game game = new Game();

                game.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                game.League = reader.GetString(1);
                game.VisitorTeam = reader.GetString(2);
                game.HomeTeam = reader.GetString(3);
                game.Date = new DateTime(reader.GetInt64(4));
                //game.Date = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetInt64(4)));
                game.VisitorScore = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(5));
                game.HomeScore = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(6));

                enumerable.Add(game);
            }
        }
    }

    return enumerable;
}
```

Here is the table CREATE:

```
public void CreateTable()
{
    string sql =
        @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GAMES(
                                       ID              INTEGER                     PRIMARY KEY,                                               
                                       LEAGUE          TEXT                        NOT NULL,                                                                 
                                       VISITORTEAM     TEXT                        NOT NULL,                                                                 
                                       HOMETEAM        TEXT                        NOT NULL,                                                                 
                                       DATETIME        INTEGER                     NOT NULL,
                                       VISITORSCORE    INTEGER                     NOT NULL,
                                       HOMESCORE       INTEGER                     NOT NULL 
                                       )";

    // if the database table already exists, this will throw an exception.
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, Db))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

How I currently sort (too slow)

```
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
 bool descending)
    {
        return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                          : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
```

usage:

```
games = games.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Date.Ticks, false).ToList();
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM GAMES ORDER BY ID

Comment: the Id is a hash and does not guarantee order

Comment: Show the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't insert the "chronologically ordered ascending timestamp" in the database aswell, and order by that column when retrieving the results?

It's not a good idea to maintain an order of a list based it's order in the database. Both columns and rows should be able to occur in any order, the database doesn't care about that and neither should you.

I had a similar problem in a project and in the end, I went with the solution you want to avoid, a index column. This because i needed the possibility to change the index however I wanted. And yes, I agree that solution is icky.

Comment: The DateTime in the table is the number ticks since Jan 1 1900. Is there a fast way to sort on that? I am currently using the code snippet that I added to the post (see above) for sorting. It is very slow.

Comment: Just sort by that column in the SQL query.

command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GAMES ORDER BY DATETIME";

Comment: I also tried out your sorting method with 100k dummy "games" without any performance hit. Took 32ms to sort that list (any realistic values were sorted instantly), so i'm not sure you've pinpointed the problem here.